# What files to backup on Lighttpd+MySQL+PHP server

Tags: mysql, backup, php, web-server, lighttpd

I have a VPS with CentOS 5. I would like to create backup of:

- all my config files
- tweaks of database, php, server a databases
- cron settings
- website files
- installed applications and their settings (?)

What files should i take into account?

I don't want to miss any file that will be necessary to restore fast my webserver in case of any failure.

And I don't want to create whole backup because entire VPS has like 30 GB of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question in response would be; why is your web server using 30Gb of data?  I'm assuming that *your* data (web files, database etc) does not weigh in at 30Gb - lestwise you would be wanting to back that up.  I would say, trim your web server to what are its bare essentials.

Otherwise; you hit the usual suspects.  You should be backing up lighttpd's config files, php's ini files and mysql's config files in addition to your data.  I would also recommend backing up the log files from the system (if you're not sending them to a centralized syslog server) to aid in diagnosing what went wrong with the original system in case of failure.

If your user configuration is sufficiently complex (more than just the usual mysql, php and lighttpd users - I would also suggest looking into a federated system (LDAP, OpenDirectory or Windows Domains depending on what OS your server is running) to facilitate quick fail-over to another server.